# error in grader test. Infinite recursion error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, retrofit

I am learning Spring MVC online. As part of my course, I have to develop a Cloud Video Service. Specifications are mentioned here. 
https://github.com/juleswhite/mobile-cloud-asgn1

Below is my controller class.

```
@Controller
```

public class VideosController {
    private final AtomicLong currentId = new AtomicLong(1L);

```
//A Map to hold incoming Video meta data
private HashMap<Long, Video> videoMap = new HashMap<Long, Video>(); 

//Receives GET requests to /video and returns the current list
// list of videos in memory
@RequestMapping(value = "/video", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Video> getVideoList() throws IOException{
    List<Video> resultList = new ArrayList<Video>();        
    for(Long id : videoMap.keySet()) {
        resultList.add(videoMap.get(id));
    }       
    return resultList;
}

//Receives POST requests to /video and adds the video object
//created from request data to the Map
@RequestMapping(value = "/video", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody() Video addVideoMetadata(@RequestBody Video data)
{   
    //create a Video object     
    Video video = Video.create().withContentType(data.getContentType())
            .withDuration(data.getDuration())
            .withSubject(data.getSubject())
            .withTitle(data.getTitle()).build();

    //set the id for the video
    long videoId = currentId.incrementAndGet();
    video.setId(videoId);

    //set the URL for this Video
    String videoURL = getDataUrl(videoId);
    video.setDataUrl(videoURL);         
    //save the Video metadata object to map
    Video v = save(video);
    return v;       
}

// Receives POST requests to /video/{id}/data e.g. /videoa/2/data
// uploads the video file sent as MultipartFile 
// and writes it to the disc
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/{id}/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public  @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<VideoStatus> uploadVideo
        (@RequestParam("data") MultipartFile data,
        @PathVariable("id") long id,
        HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws IOException 
{   
    // if video with id not present
    if(!videoMap.containsKey(id)) {
        System.out.println(" this id not present");         
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        //return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        //read the input stream
        in = data.getInputStream();
    }
    catch(IOException ie){
        System.out.println("Exception reading inputstream");
    }
    finally {
        in.close();
    }       
    //get the video
    Video v = videoMap.get(id); 
    //write it to disk
    VideoFileManager.get().saveVideoData(v, in);
    VideoStatus vs = new VideoStatus(VideoStatus.VideoState.READY); 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(vs, HttpStatus.OK);
    //response.setStatus(200);
    //return new ResponseEntity<>(vs, HttpStatus.OK);

}   

//Reads GET request to /vide/{id}/data and returns the video
//binary data as output stream
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/{id}/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<OutputStream> getBinaryData(
        @PathVariable("id") long videoId,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    //if id is incorrect 
    if(!videoMap.containsKey(videoId)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }   
    //get the video from Map
    Video outVideo = videoMap.get(videoId);
    VideoFileManager vm = VideoFileManager.get();
    //write the binary data to OutputStream
    OutputStream os  = response.getOutputStream();
    vm.copyVideoData(outVideo, os);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(os, HttpStatus.OK);
}

//save incoming video metadata to a Map
public Video save(Video v) {
    checkAndSetId(v);
    if(!videoMap.containsKey(v.getId())) {
        videoMap.put(v.getId(), v);
    }
    return v;
}


//helper method to generate url for video
private String getDataUrl(long videoId){
    String url = getUrlBaseForLocalServer() + "/video/" + videoId + "/data";
    return url;
}

private String getUrlBaseForLocalServer() {
       HttpServletRequest request = 
           ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
       String base = 
          "http://"+request.getServerName() 
          + ((request.getServerPort() != 80) ? ":"+request.getServerPort() : "");
       return base;
}

private void checkAndSetId(Video entity) {
    if(entity.getId() == 0){
        entity.setId(currentId.incrementAndGet());
    }
}
```

}

Now, I pass all the tests in AutoGradingTest.java Unit code but not the testAddVideoData(). It gives a Socket Time out error, followed by Infinite recursion error, pointing to line number 159 in the AutoGradingTest.java
Logically, my code seems to be fine. Lot of other learners are facing problem with thirstiest case too but there is no help from the course instructors.
Can somebody please help me here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `line number 159` ?? Please post the stack traces.

Comment: @papaya it is the line '''byte[] retrievedFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(videoData);''' in AutoGradingTest.java

Comment: You expect us to find `AutoGradingTest.class`?  Where is it?

Comment: Adding top few lines from stack trace as it is running into hundreds of lines  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState["httpChannel"]->org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$HttpChannelOverHttp["state"]->org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState["httpChannel"]->org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$HttpChannelOve

Comment: Dear@papaya, sorry for the trouble. The codebase is at the link shared by me in the first post. Actually there are dependencies between classes and there are quite a few, so i put the link. It was not possible to put all the code in the post. Thanks

Comment: This is the link. <https://github.com/juleswhite/mobile-cloud-asgn1>

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Issues ideally should be focussed and you should do your own investigation first and post what you might think is relevant here.

Comment: Well I tried to add some print statements to trace the code execution. As I said, I am new to Spring MVC and taking this course to learn. Problem is that the code that gies an error is not written by me and hence I am unable to move ahead. Logically, my uploadVideo method looks ok as I am reading multipart data and trying to save it to disk.

Comment: Use an IDE and try debugging values. Your question is too broad.

Comment: @papaya thanks for the input. I did some further debugging and have been able to move ahead on this.